# What are the best sites/forums to contribute/share gtksharp code using Mono

Tags: mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm new to the world of Mono and GTKSharp programming, having come from using visual studio on Windows it's a refreshing change to develop on Ubuntu using MonoDevelop.

I would like to find sites that I can contribute to and learn from, I have written a small class that implements some very easy to use dialog boxes such as a messagebox and filebrowser etc and would just like somewhere to share my code and get critique / input from other developers, and who knows maybe even help some people along the way.

This is my first post on stackoverflow so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This does sound like somthing I'd use too!

Answer (score 2):

The [Mono mailing lists](http://www.mono-project.com/Mailing_Lists) would be a good point to start.

You want the [Gtk# mailing list](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/gtk-sharp-list).

Comment: Thanks, I'm now subscribed to the Gtk# mailing list, let's see where we go with that.